# Can't sign in via Google on iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, cordova, google-signin

I'm running a cordova app that uses the Google sign in integration.  When I follow the links to login (put in email, put in password, pass 2FA), I get redirected to an error.

```
400. That's an error
Error: admin_policy_enforced
Open the Device policy App to continue
Learn more (link)
> Request Details
That's all we know
```

I have been able to fix similar issues by using the Google Device Policy app on a physical device, however I do not know how to get this working in the iOS Simulator environment where I cannot install the Google Device Policy application.

I'm currently using

```
Cordova 4.5.4
Xcode 10.1
iOS 12.1
iPad-Pro 11 inch (simulated)
```

Comment: did you get any solution for this yet?

Comment: Nope, it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to sign in with a Google account that is managed by my company, hence the error mentioning the Device Policy App.  And that app is required when signing in on a physical device.